# CircleCI to TestFlight

Tags: testflight, circleci

I followed [this](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2016/07/19/circleci-test-deply-ios-app/) article to upload my build from CircleCI to TestFlight.

I was able to upload the build from CircleCI to Testflight. The problem is I am getting an error "Missing Beta Entitlement" in front of my build.
I googled and found that I have to include "beta-reports-active" key in my provision profile and entitlement file.

1. I added "beta-reports-active" in my entitlement file only and then I tried again. I got this error "Your provisioning profile is missing beta-reports-active".
2. Then I manually edited provision file and added "beta-reports-active". Then I tried again and I got error "Unable to parse provision profile".
3. Then I replaced my provision profile (which was distribution) with App Store provision profile. Then I tried again and got this error "Code Signing is required".

My circle.yml file

```
machine:

  environment:
    GYM_CODE_SIGNING_IDENTITY: "My Code sigining identity"

  xcode:
    version: "8.0"


deployment:
  beta_distribution:
    branch: master
    commands:
      - gym
      - ipa distribute:itunesconnect -i 21321478 --upload --verbose
```

Please help me on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I was able to solve it by myself. I added some flags with gym and that worked.

```
- gym --scheme "myScheme" --workspace "my.xcworkspace" --export_method app-store --use_legacy_build_api false
```